# VBA Regex substitution codes

Tags: regex, vba

any experience with vba regex substition codes?
I've tried the followings, which are working both on regex101.com and on regexr.com.

```
$&
\0
```

They are unfortunately not working in my VBA code.
Any similar experience?

Example: https://regex101.com/r/5Fb0EV/1

VBA code:

```
    Dim MsgTxt As String
    ...

    strPattern = "(Metodo di pagamento).*\r\x07?.*"  
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = strPattern
        MsgTxt = regEx.Replace(MsgTxt, "\0#END")
    End With
```

Input string:

```
Metodo di pagamento selezionato: 
Mastercard
```

Expected ouput:

```
Metodo di pagamento selezionato: 
Mastercard #END
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: code, input and output added

Comment: can't display here but each line has a chr(7) at the beginning

Comment: @QHarr Thanks but still not answered in linked post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code:

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim MsgTxt As String

    MsgTxt = Chr(7) & "Metodo di pagamento selezionato:" & vbCr & Chr(7) & "Mastercard "
    With New RegExp
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(Metodo di pagamento.*\r\x07?.*)"
        MsgTxt = .Replace(MsgTxt, "$1#END")
    End With
    Debug.Print MsgTxt

End Sub
```

Input

```
Metodo di pagamento selezionato:
Mastercard
```

Output

```
Metodo di pagamento selezionato:
Mastercard #END
```